# Is it better to increase process niceness or limit number of cores used on a shared system?

Tags: performance, resources, processing-efficiency, multi-user, concurrent-processing

I've often worked in settings where several users have access to the same machine for computationally intensive tasks. The machines in question are standard linux machines (no docker/kubernetes or similar).

In some cases, there has been a policy to never use all the machine's cores for a given task to not hog resources. In other cases, the policy has been to run non-critical tasks with high nice values for the child processes, to allow priority to more important tasks.

Which is the better or more 'polite' way of allocating resources on a multi-user system? If neither is unilaterally better, what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Dear Community members,this question is important, voting to close important questions prevent learning from answering such important topic. Preventing this to be addressed causes many more such questions to repeat, as nobody will ever find a reasonable answer for this repeating and repeating and repeating problem. If Site policy is interpreted so that close important question in this very manner, the Community is shooting into ours own feet. If in doubts, just read how many times the "parallel-processing" questions are principally misleading, as not understanding this very problem.Let it stay